# Normalize a vector of 3d coordinates to be in between 0 and 1

Tags: 3d, coordinates, normalization

I have a huge vector of 3D coordinates and i want to normalize them so that they lie inside a cube of dimension [0,1] x [0,1] x [0,1] (i.e, each x,y,z of the coordinate should be between 0 and 1), what i am doing is dividing all the coordinates by the max length of the 3D coordinate in this vector but in this way i cant handle the coordinates with negative values. Can anyone suggest what would be the proper way to normalize these coordinates?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

just divide each component by the length of the vector:

length = sqrt( x^2 + y^2 + z^2 )

so your normalized vector is:

v = ( x / length, y / length, z / length )

Comment: I want to keep them between 0 and 1, what if a for eg. x is negative? i want to handle that case as well

Comment: ok, just divide the normalized vector by 2 and sum vector (0.5,0.5,0.5)

Comment: Also, he said vector of 3d coords, so you might need to find the range between the upper and lower bounds of each axis and use the largest value to scale the rest as above

Comment: @JordiCruzado can you explain how this actually works or what it's doing? Its hard for me to think about the "length" of a vector when its only 3 points. As far as I know thats a SINGLE point, not a vector?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/794481/tallboy. If you think that the 3 components of the vector (x, y, z) are the coordinates of a point in space, the length is just the distance of this point to the origin, point 0,0,0 (distance = x,y,z - 0,0,0 = x,y,z). So, if you divide this vector (each of its components) by the length (distance to the origin) you get a new vector with a length 1 (distance to the origin = 1) and in the same direction of the original vector, ie, pointing to the point x,y,x from the origin

Answer (score 3):

As a example we define a matrix called v:

```py
import numpy as np

v = np.array([[[-1,2,3], [4,5,6]]])
v
array([[[-1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]]])
```

And also a range:

```py
new_range = (0, 1)
max_range = max(new_range)
min_range = min(new_range)
```

The first thing I do here is to see what is the current range of numbers between the minimum and the maximum. Since we want the minimum to be 0.0 and the maximum 1.0, we must divide the range (1.0 - 0.0, maximum minus the minimum), that is 1.0, between the old range of numbers.

```py
scaled_unit = 1.0 / (np.max(v) - np.min(v))
```

Or generally (using the range `new_range` described above):

```py
scaled_unit = (max_range - min_range) / (np.max(v) - np.min(v))
```

With this division one achieves what will be considered the new unit.

To convert each old value into the new one, we multiply it by the scaled unit and subtract the minimum value multiplied by the scaled unit again. Then we sum `min_range`:

```py
v*scaled_unit - np.min(v)*scaled_unit + min_range
array([[[0.        , 0.42857143, 0.57142857],
        [0.71428571, 0.85714286, 1.        ]]])
```

Then we get all values to keep their proportions between them and yet be contained between 0.0 for the minimum value and 1.0 for the maximum. This also can be used to scale to whatever range we need.

For example:

```py
v = np.array([[[-1,2,3], [4,5,6]]])

def scale_numpy_array(arr, min_v, max_v):
    new_range = (min_v, max_v)
    max_range = max(new_range)
    min_range = min(new_range)
    scaled_unit = (max_range - min_range) / (np.max(arr) - np.min(arr))
    return arr*scaled_unit - np.min(arr)*scaled_unit + min_range


scale_numpy_array(v, -1, 1)
array([[[-1.        , -0.14285714,  0.14285714],
        [ 0.42857143,  0.71428571,  1.        ]]])


scale_numpy_array(v, -10, -1)
array([[[-10.        ,  -6.14285714,  -4.85714286],
        [ -3.57142857,  -2.28571429,  -1.        ]]])
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer with more comments, sorry. English is not my language and I wanted to help despite it.